# If $f: S\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is differentiable of class $C^r$ at each point $x_0$ of $S$, then $f$ may be extended to a $C^r$ function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

This problem has already been posted here without an answer: [$f$ may be extended to a $C^r$ function $h : A \to R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479346/f-may-be-extended-to-a-cr-function-h-a-to-r).

I have thought about this problem but I do not know how I can begin to solve it, I think that the following theorem can be used but I do not know how. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you very much.

[image]